# How can I temporarily make the window I'm working on to be fullscreen in vim?

Tags: vim

I use vim, and usually have more than one vertical/horizental window open, usually editing c++ header files alongside cpp files. How can I temporarily make the window I'm working on to be fullscreen, edit what I want, and then exit fullscreen?

By fullscreen I mean to fit vim window only, and not my total display screen.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

If I understand what you're asking, I think you'll find the [ZoomWin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=508) plugin helpful ([GitHub](https://github.com/vim-scripts/ZoomWin)).  If you've got a bunch of split windows, and you want to temporarily make the current window the only visible one, you can hit `<C-w>o`.  When you want to revert to the previous split state, hit `<C-w>o` again.

**[Edit] Note on key mappings:**

The default key mapping for this plugin is `<C-w>o`, but that conflicts with a default Vim key mapping.  By default, that does `:only`, which makes the current window the only window.  If you'd like to retain that functionality, you can remap ZoomWin to another key.  I remap it to `<C-w>w`, because I like to use the `:only` option as well.  Here's my mapping:

```
nnoremap <silent> <C-w>w :ZoomWin<CR>
```

Note that this also overrides a default Vim mapping, related to moving to other visible windows (`:help CTRL-W_w`), but I never used that one anyway.

Comment: I'm using it now, when I press <C-w>o it works ok, but when I press <C-w>o again to restore, a message is shown that only one windows is open, and it does nothing more

Comment: Sorry, I don't get that problem.  Possible there's a conflict with another plugin or key mapping that you have.  Try it out in isolation.  There may also be an issue with your Vim compatibility mode setting (`:help cpoptions`).  It works fine for me in conjunction with many other plugins, though.

Comment: I just realized that I actually rebound this key, and `<C-w>o` without the plugin does what you describe in your comment (I use the default `<C-w>o` constantly but I wasn't thinking).  Based on your comment, I suspect you just hadn't installed the plugin when you commented.  Since you accepted I'm assuming you've worked it out.  See my edited answer above for some more info.

Comment: It works now with :ZoomWin, but I have to find some keys others than `<C-w>w`. It conflicts too :D, Thank you.

Comment: I would use the `ctrl-p` plugin and the default behavior of `<C-w>o` to get the desired result the OP requires (vs using the ZoomWin plugin). Also @duskwuff 's answer works without using plugins.

Answer (score 175):

<kbd>Ctrl+W</kbd><kbd>_</kbd> will maximize a window vertically.

<kbd>Ctrl+W</kbd><kbd>|</kbd> will maximize a window horizontally.

So far as I'm aware, there is no way to restore the previous layout after these actions, but <kbd>Ctrl+W</kbd><kbd>=</kbd> will resize all windows to equal sizes.

Comment: Thanks. This is nice because it doesn't require a plugin.

Answer (score 61):

An option could be to pursue the editing in a new tab. The following command opens the active buffer into a new tab allowing you to see the buffer in the hole vim window.

```
:tab split
```

And close the tab when you're done:

```
:tabc
```

**Edit:**

You can always use the following command to use `tt` as a shortcut (or better add it to your `.vimrc`):

```
:noremap tt :tab split<CR>
```

and close is when you're done :

```
:wq
```

Comment: This is really great because you don't need a plugin.  Just tested it out and it works great!  Adding to my .vimrc :)

Comment: Whoa, is there any way to make this a toggle?  That would be so slick!

Comment: @racarate `:noremap tt  :tab split<CR>` made it convenient for me (followed by `:wq` after finished editing)

Comment: @kevin that's a great shortcut! Feel free to edit the answer and add it as an edit. I think it could help people that don't necessarily read comments!

Comment: `noremap <leader>w :wq<cr>` is convenient for quitting

Comment: I think this should really be the accepted answer, because you're showing the power of not thinking of windows, tabs and buffers having a 1-on-1 relationship. IMO, `vim` starts to outshine EDIs as soon as you use different tabs for different views on the same buffers.

Answer (score 16):

Use <kbd>Ctrl w</kbd><kbd>_</kbd> to maximize the current window vertically.

These are some useful commands that help work with windows:

**:e filename**      - *edit another file*

**:split filename**  - *split window and load another file*

**ctrl-w up arrow**  - *move cursor up a window*

**ctrl-w ctrl-w**    - *move cursor to another window (cycle)*

**ctrl-w=**          - *make all equal size*

**10 ctrl-w+**       - *increase window size by 10 lines*

**:vsplit file**     - *vertical split*

**:sview file**      - *same as split, but readonly*

**:hide**            - *close current window*

**:only**            - *keep only this window open*

**:ls**              - *show current buffers*

**:b 2**             - *open buffer #2 in this window*

Comment: `:h resize` Set current window **height** to N (default: highest possible)

Answer (score 3):

Manoj somewhat answered with a lot more useful info, but as a first step this is what works for me:

`:hide`: Hide the current buffer - with a two-buffer split, this makes the other buffer full screen. Unlike `:only`, this command *does not* close unmodified buffers so you can *unhide* them.

`:unhide`: Re-create splits for each open buffer

The `unhide` command does not restore the previous layout, so you will have to manually rearrange your windows if needed ex. using one of these for simple vertical/horizontal splits (this is <kbd>CTRL-W</kbd> followed by the uppercase navigation letter - release <kbd>CTRL-W</kbd> before entering the letter):

<kbd>CTRL-W</kbd> <kbd>SHIFT-H</kbd>: Move window to the far left
<kbd>CTRL-W</kbd> <kbd>SHIFT-J</kbd>: Move window to the very bottom
<kbd>CTRL-W</kbd> <kbd>SHIFT-K</kbd>: Move window to the very top
<kbd>CTRL-W</kbd> <kbd>SHIFT-L</kbd>: Move window to the far right

These are the same keys used for navigation, without <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> (lowercase navigation letters):

<kbd>CTRL-W</kbd> <kbd>H</kbd>: Move focus to the left window
<kbd>CTRL-W</kbd> <kbd>J</kbd>: Move focus to the bottom window
<kbd>CTRL-W</kbd> <kbd>K</kbd>: Move focus to the top window
<kbd>CTRL-W</kbd> <kbd>L</kbd>: Move focus to the right window

The <kbd>H</kbd>, <kbd>J</kbd>, <kbd>K</kbd> and <kbd>L</kbd> keys alone move the cursor - arrow keys on the keyboard may work as well for navigation.

Answer (score 2):

An awesome plugin for toggling windows fullscreen is [**vim-maximizer**](https://github.com/szw/vim-maximizer).

After it's installed you can simply use `<F3>` (default shortcut) to toggle fullscreen on the window.

You can also customize the shortcut keys, for example if you wanted to use `<C-w> z` (similar to tmux shortcut):

```
nnoremap <silent><C-w>z :MaximizerToggle<CR>
vnoremap <silent><C-w>z :MaximizerToggle<CR>gv
inoremap <silent><C-w>z <C-o>:MaximizerToggle<CR>
```

Answer (score 2):

I've tried ZoomWin and a few others. The problem is, they all destroy and try to re-create the windows. This is especially problematic with custom plugins like NERDTree, Tagbar and a few others. Icons and fonts are not drawn properly, sizes are messed up etc..

zoomwintab.vim is a simple zoom window plugin that uses vim's tabs feature to zoom into a window inspired by ZoomWin plugin but in a non-destructive manner.

https://github.com/troydm/zoomwintab.vim

I use Tmux, so I mapped it to `<leader> z` to stay in sync with tmux's `<prefix> z`

```
nnoremap <leader>z :ZoomWinTabToggle<CR>
```

Answer (score 1):

Somehow the ZoomWin plugin did not work at all for me, my experience was kind of what arithran says. I couldn't find other plugins so I wrote this:

```
function! ToggleZoom(zoom)
  if exists("t:restore_zoom") && (a:zoom == v:true || t:restore_zoom.win != winnr())
      exec t:restore_zoom.cmd
      unlet t:restore_zoom
  elseif a:zoom
      let t:restore_zoom = { 'win': winnr(), 'cmd': winrestcmd() }
      exec "normal \<C-W>\|\<C-W>_"
  endif
endfunction

augroup restorezoom
    au WinEnter * silent! :call ToggleZoom(v:false)
augroup END
nnoremap <silent> <Leader>+ :call ToggleZoom(v:true)<CR>
```

It creates the effect. You use the mapped key (Leader and + in my case) to toggle between maximized / previous layout. If you change to another split in the same tab, maximization turns off.